# MongoDB, How to use uri connection with special charaters `@` on the password

Tags: mongodb

I have au user who has special characters in its password. The password is `123@456`. I tried to escape the character but it still doesn't work. Below is the method I tried:

```
$ mongo mongodb://user5:123%40456@localhost:28017/admin
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://user5:123%40456@localhost:28017/admin
2017-02-14T12:11:47.571+1100 E QUERY    [main] Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I can use below way to do the connection:

```
$ mongo mongodb://localhost:28017/admin -u user5 -p 123@456
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:28017/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.0
```

But I am looking for a way to connect through URI. How to use this `@` character as a password in URI connection in MongoDB? In this way, I can use the same URI for shell connection and driver connection.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: url encode your password then connect using the following uri

```
mongodb://user5:123%40456@localhost:28017/dbName?authSource=dbName&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
```

reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-connection-options

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't connect MongoDB by using **connection URI** with special charaters `@` in password.

Because as far as I know, Mongo is using standart regex to support connection string URI.I tried to read the mongo shell and driver code and I found the reason.You can see the [connection](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/legacy/src/mongo/client/dbclient.cpp#L1660-L1719) part and the [parser](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/client/mongo_uri.cpp#L78-L162) part from github.

Here is the part of code in [mongo-cxx-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/legacy/src/mongo/client/dbclient.cpp#L82-L97) .

```
namespace {
const char kMongoDBURL[] =
    // scheme: non-capturing
    "mongodb://"

    // credentials: two inner captures for user and password
    "(?:([^:]+)(?::([^@]+))?@)?"

    // servers: grabs all host:port or UNIX socket names
    "((?:(?:[^\\/]+|/.+.sock?),?)+)"

    // database: matches anything but the chars that cannot
    // be part of a MongoDB database name.
    "(?:/([^/\\.\\ \"*<>:\\|\\?]*))?"

    // options
    "(?:\\?(?:(.+=.+)&?)+)*";

} // namespace
```

We can see that if your connection URI is `mongodb://user5:123@456@localhost:28017/admin`,it will parse this string and return `mongodb://da1:abc@` rather than `mongodb://da1:abc@123@`.

As a matter of fact, I tried to set user password to `abc^&*123` and connect MongoDB by using mongo shell with single quote and I did not escape any special characters.And it works.

```
➜  mongo 'mongodb://users:abc^&*123@localhost:27017'
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://users:abc^&*123@localhost:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.0
Server has startup warnings:
2017-02-14T11:58:20.623+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

So I think **connection URI** supports other special characters without escaping them but doesn't support `@` character in password.

However,you can try this:

```
➜  mongo admin -u user5 -p 'abc@123'
MongoDB shell version v3.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.4.0
Server has startup warnings:
2017-02-14T14:15:06.109+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Also you can connect MongoDB with other tools like [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) or pymongo.They are very supportive of this. By the way,I would recommend to change the password to another one that does not include `@` character.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update**

Have a look at [SERVER-27997](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27997) and SERVER-25059 is tracking that bug.